How to persist user session using ProtectedSessionStorage and Cookie based Authentication .NET8 Blazor WebApp
My application is using global InteractiveServerRenderMode without prerendering, but my Login component is using static SSR so that I can access HttpContext for cookie authentication. Below is how I set the rendermode in App.razor : 
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />   <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" /> 
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false); } 

  Below is the method that handles the authentication in my LogIn Component //Account/LogIn: 
     public async Task HandleLogin()
     {
         isLoading = true; // Hide spinner
         await Task.Delay(2000);
      
         var results = await Authenticate(Input);
         if (results.User is not null)
         {
            
             var claims = new List<Claim>
                 {
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, results.User.PersonId.ToString()),
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, results.User.Login.UserName),
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,results.User.Email),
                    
                 };
           
             var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
             var newUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    
             var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
             {
                 AllowRefresh = true,
                 ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
                 IsPersistent = Input.RememberMe,
             };
    
             //await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("UserData", results);
    
             await Context.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, newUser, authProperties);            
             RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
    
            
         }
         else
         {
             errorMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(results.Message) ? "Error: Invalid login credentials" : results.Message;
         }
        
     }

 Since ProtectedSessionStore is not available in static SSR what's the ideal way of persisting the user data so I can access on other interactive components?

Maybe you can create a scoped service, persist your object, and DI it into your components and access the object?

Thanks, I will have to use a scoped service.
